# Why are there two different results for the numbering of <dl> tags in Edge and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

The following snippets produce different results in Edge and Firefox:

```css
dd {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  counter-increment: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
<dl>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>One</dd>
  <dd>Two</dd>
  <dd>Three</dd>
</dl>
```

In Edge, the `<dl>` list correctly starts with index 1. On the other hand, that of Firefox is 4.

After I deleted the `<ul>` node above the `<dl>` tag, the numbering of the `<dd>` tags started from 1. I don't know why this happened.

I want the `<dd>` tags to start from position 1 in Firefox. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Firefox is using the same counter for LI in UL, and DD in DL - but doesn't reset it on the DL element level.

Try adding `dl { counter-reset: list-item; }`

Comment: What's improper about Firefox not resetting it? Why should dl reset the counter by default?

Comment: @Alohci why shouldn't it? :-) If you had two `ol` elements one after the other, you'd expect the numbering of the items of the second one to start at 1 again. Not sure why this should be different, if you had multiple `dl` instead.

Comment: Because the [HTML5 specification rendering section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#lists) states that browsers are expected to include `ol, ul, menu { counter-reset: list-item; }` in their user-agent style sheet. There is no such expectation for `dl` elements.

Comment: @Alohci thanks, so Chrome's behavior is not actually covered by the spec then. So the above should be added for all browsers, if the desired result is what the OP wanted here.